# How can I return a subtype of the specified return value (in this case interface{})?

Tags: go

I have an interface that defines one parameter to have type `func(interface{}, proto.Message) interface{}` and I'm trying to pass something of type `func reduceMsg(a interface{}, b proto.Message) []*PersistentData` to it. This results in the following compiler error:

```
Cannot use reduceMsg (type func(a interface{}, b proto.Message) []*PersistentData as type func(interface{}, proto.Message) interface{}
```

What is the reason for this error, and how can I work around it? It seems like returning a more specific type than `interface{}` should be legal. Here's a simple complete example that illustrates the issue:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var t func() interface{} = func() []string { return []string{} }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types

Comment: That seems like a flaw in the language. Especially given that the following is perfectly legal: `var t interface{} = []string{}`.

Comment: Your example is not actually relevant to the problem explained: assignability rules (your example code) and interface implementation rules (your actual problem) are different.

Comment: @jonderry: go interfaces are a separate concept from variant types, and `func(a interface{}, b proto.Message) []*PersistentData` is a separate type from `func(a interface{}, b proto.Message) interface{}`. Having one part of the function signature assignable to another part of the function signature does not make the overall type equal. It helps to work with a language for a while before declaring how the language works "a flaw".

Comment: @JimB btw, it's surprisingly not much in the standard on the rules of how a type is checked whether it implements an interface or not. They have "A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to implement the interface." but there is no (?) definition on how "being a superset" property is evaluated.

Comment: @zerkms: it's all in the spec, but It is hard to reconcile how a newcomer reads the spec compared to one who knows it already. Doesn't this cover it? https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Comment: @JimB it does not (?) cover how method sets are checked for equality.

Comment: @zerkms: yeah, maybe it's not explicit there. I guess my assumption was always that because a method set must match exactly, there's not really any detail to go into, it simply must match. That's probably why the covariant question ended up in the FAQ rather than expanding on it in the spec.

Comment: @JimB If the return type of the function is assignable to the return type in the declaration, then the function should be assignable. This is true in most other languages that have function types. A function is not like a container type that requires invariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referencing the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments),

> In assignments, each value must be assignable to the type of the operand to which it is assigned, with the following special cases:
>
> - Any typed value may be assigned to the blank identifier.
> - If an untyped constant is assigned to a variable of interface type or the blank identifier, the constant is first converted to its default type.
> - If an untyped boolean value is assigned to a variable of interface type or the blank identifier, it is first converted to type bool.

Assignability

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.
> - x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

In general, Go doesn't allow you to implicitly convert values from one type to another, with the exception of being able to use concrete-typed objects as though they were interfaces (that they implement).

In this particular case, since your function doesn't actually return an `interface{}`, the compiler would have to do some extra work to wrap up the return value as an `interface{}` and return it; if you really want to accomplish what you're trying you can do this explicitly yourself:

```
type Foo struct {
    X int
}
func create(x int) Foo {
    return Foo{X: x}
}
func main() {
    var f func(int) interface{} = func(x int) interface{} {
        return create(x)
    }
}
```

which is basically doing (explicitly) the wrapping operation that you want the runtime to do implicitly.

Comment: Code can be found here https://play.golang.org/p/pNKfcc95Uo9.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the object is the whole function signature. If the signature don't match, then it's not the same type and can't be assigned that way.

Anything can be assigned to the empty interface, because all types satisfy the interface, but in your problem neither type is the empty interface, you just have a function that returns an empty interface.

Not because a part of the function can be assigned to another it makes it the same. The type is the whole function signature. I think it's the same logic behind not being able to assign an `int` to an `int8`. You can cast them if you want, but for go, they are separate types and you need to deal with making the necessary conversions to be able to assign them.

What you can do is change your second function signature to return an empty interface like this:

```
func(interface{}, proto.Message) interface{}

func reduceMsg(a interface{}, b proto.Message) interface{} {
    var a []*PersistentData
    // do something here
    return a
}
```

This way the function signature is the same, so it's consider the same type and you are returning an `[]*PersistentData`. Of course you will need to do a type assertion before using it as such because the program will treat it as an `{}interface` because that is the type that the function returned.

Comment: "I think it's the same logic behind not being able to assign an int to an int8" --- I cannot agree; You cannot assign an `int` to `int8` because this may cause data loss. But covariance is a whole different story: covariant types compatible: `[]string` is assignable to the `interface{}`. Co/contra-variance support is a higher level operation, than just types assignability.

Comment: I know it's a different concept and they might have motivations for designing the language that way, but the reason why that is not allowed is the same. In go if it's a different type you can't do an assignment. And the functions types are defined by the whole function signature. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types